# Mixitup - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using default [mixitup](http://mixitup.io/) configuration `$('#id').mixitup()`, I am adding a filter button dynamically by appending html code for button `<li>` tag. And calling the same function again instantly after adding html code to the page, in order to make the new button work. After clicking some filter buttons on the page (even if I don't press the new one) animation effects break and on the browser console I see:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined error.

The error occurs on line 937:

```
$toshow.each(function () {
    var data = this.data;
    data.tX = data.finalPos.left - data.showInterPos.left; //HERE
```

I saw on documentation how to add new images to the list by using jquery after method, but there are no explanations about how to dynamically add filter buttons and initialize them on the fly.

Is the described behaviour expected?
That means I am doing something wrong. Then, how to initialize the new filter button correctly?

I am using Mixitup 1.5.6 (latest) with jQuery 1.10.2 (Also tried with jQuery 2.0.3).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that either data.finalPos or data.showInterPos is undefined. console.log data after you define it to see if you even have those keys

```
$toshow.each(function () {
    var data = this.data;
    console.log(data); //here
    data.tX = data.finalPos.left - data.showInterPos.left;
```

Comment: Are you suggesting a debug operation on the Mixitup plugin source code?

Comment: Is the code above the source code? I assumed it was code that you wrote.

Either way, data.finalPos or data.showInterPos is undefined. You need to see why it's undefined.

Comment: In order to have such a functionality, instead of washing your hands and write it on your own, you try to use these great ready plugins sometimes :) I guess I should wait for anothor answer, thank you anyways ;)

Comment: I generally have to re-write other plugins so much that I've learned to just start from scratch myself. :) I hope you find your answer.